# Deriving an associated token account address

Tags: anchor, anchor-spl

How can I derive an associated token account address for a given wallet address and token mint?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example in Anchor:

```
use spl_associated_token_account::get_associated_token_address;
let token_address = get_associated_token_address(
     &owner_pubkey,
     &some_mint,
);
```

Src: https://docs.rs/anchor-spl/latest/anchor_spl/associated_token/fn.get_associated_token_address.html

Here's an example in JavaScript:

```
import { getAssociatedTokenAddress } from "@solana/spl-token";
import { PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";

const mint  = new PublicKey(''); // add your mint
const owner = new PublicKey(''); // add owner wallet

(async ()=>{
    let ata = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mint, owner);
    console.log(ata.toString());
})
```

Src: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#getAssociatedTokenAddress

Comment: is `get_associated_token_address` guaranted to generate the **same address** for the same mint address and SOL account, each time it's called?

Answer (score 0):

By this code you can get associated token account:

pub fn get_associated_token_address(
wallet_address: &Pubkey,
token_mint_address: &Pubkey
) -> Pubkey